# create multiple rows for each month from date range

Tags: sql, netezza

the source has data like
Colum1| Colum2| Colum3| Colum4| Colum5| Start_date| End_date

A       |       B|      A|      B|      A|      1/1/2021|   4/1/2021|

is it possible to get data as follows using query in netizza

Colum1| Colum2| Colum3| Colum4| Colum5| Month

A|      B   |   A   |   B   |   A   |   1-Jan-21

A|      B   |   A   |   B   |   A   |   1-Feb-21

A|      B   |   A   |   B   |   A   |   1-Mar-21

A|      B   |   A   |   B   |   A   |   1-Apr-21

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you need a time dimension and do a ‘between-join’ against that:

```
Create temp table TimeDim as
Select ‘2010-01-01’::date+((datasliceid-1) || ‘ months’)::interval as FirstDayOfMonth
From _v_dual_dslice
;
```

Then the between-join:

```
Select * from YourTable join TimeDim
On FirstDayOfMonth between Start_date and End_Date
;
```

Can you follow ?

Lars